# Login request gets blocked by azure waf

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, gateway

In Azure Application Gateway inside Web application firewall if I enable it our deployed Spring java applications on Azure VM throws ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE after login page. All other pages which are not using spring security are working fine.

If I disabled the WAF my applications works perfectly fine.

It was working as expected earlier today(12th April)

PS: i tried disabling waf rules but not working.I also tried WAF on detection mode but again the same issue.

We have not got any firewall block logs. Also in access logs all looks perfectly fine. My application server(tomcat) logs are also looks perfectly fine.

Update: We also tried with Enabled: WAF but Disabled : All OWASP 3.0 and 2.2.9 rules but results are same application not working.

UPDATE: got update from azure support they have deployed update in my region on that day. Somehow the update have not worked as expected . So they rollback the updates.
After rollback all things are working perfectly fine.

Comment: Any update on your side?

Comment: @NancyXiong  question updated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got update from azure support they have deployed update in my region on that day. Somehow the update have not worked as expected . So they rollback the updates. After rollback all things are working perfectly fine.